# SQL Server connection string in winform application

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, connection-string

I'm going to create a SQL Server database file (`.MDF` file) in Visual Studio 2012 (C#).

I'm working on a desktop application, I've added a new `.MDF` file to project, but I don't know what is my connection string, I get this error when I try to connect to my DB:

```
SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=db\\ofoghdb.mdf");
SQLConnection.Open();
```

Error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I'm fairly familiar with SQL Server in web development, but I'm going to use it in a desktop (winform) app and I get above error

Comment: There are a few reason for this error. http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your connectionString should like this？

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\my.mdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify a full path to the database:

```
SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=C:\ofoghdb.mdf");
SQLConnection.Open();
```

See more [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-ce)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using like this to connect to a database server:

```
SqlConnection oSQLConn = new SqlConnection();
oSQLConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);" +
                            "Initial Catalog=mySQLServerDBName;" +
                            "Integrated Security=SSPI";
```

Comment: so where is m database file name?

Comment: in connection string as far as I know,we have to use dbserver name and not .mdf file name or path

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string.

```
SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=DB\MyData.mdf");
SQLConnection.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" 
    + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) 
    + "\\folder name\\Databass name " + ";Persist Security Info=False;");
```